# XPath получить текст между двумя тэгами "p"

Tags: html, парсер, xpath, parse

не получается забрать текст между < p> текст </ p>

сейчас сделал: //span[@class='_39I1Z _2ITlL _3D3LC _3NGVr embTL _1zNVc']/span/p
Заглядывает в span перечисляет теги "p", а как быть дальше?

структура:

```
<div class="" xpath="1">
<span class="_39I1Z _2ITlL _3D3LC _3NGVr embTL _1zNVc">
    <span>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <p>Текст</p>
        <p><b>Текст:</b></p>
        <p></p>
            <ul>
                <li>Текст</li>
                <li>Текст</li>
                <li>Текст</li>
            </ul>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Используйте парсер html.